# Wordpress default resize images name need to change

Tags: wordpress

I am working on wordpress(3.5.2) project but getting one issue in case of image resizing. In wordpress when i upload any image its auto resizing to thumbnail,medium and larger but the name of image taking like image-300x300.jpg but i want, for thumbnail it should be imagename-thmbnail.jpg, for medium  imagename-medium.jpg and for large imagename-large.jpg

I have made changes in Setting/Media - image re-size but it not coming consistence image name .

I do appreciate for advance help.

Comment: Googling `wordpress thumbnail file name` gives me this: http://www.doc4design.com/articles/wordpress-better-naming-of-thumbnails/

Comment: I have gone through above link but not getting below code in media.php line no 358

if ( !$suffix )
$suffix = "{$dst_w}x{$dst_h}";

Comment: The line or its location may have changed since 2009. Can you see anything similar in that file?

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you correctly Neil,
You are wanting the image files created in the WordPress upload/sizing routine to be named as follows:
    [imgname]-thmbnail.jpg,
    [imgname]-medium.jpg,
    [imgname]-large.jpg.

To the best of my knowledge this is not an option. If you can provide more detail on why you want to do this I may be able to help more.

You can declare custom image sizes in your functions.php file like so:

```
`add_image_size( 'thmbnail', 80, 80, true );`
```

and then use it in your theme:

```
`the_post_thumbnail('thmbnail');`.
```

[Just be aware WordPress uses the following natively: thumb, thumbnail, medium, large, post-thumbnail.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

Comment: Having the same problem at the moment. Are you sure you cannot change the name of the image?

Comment: This has been explored in another question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51920/set-custom-name-for-generated-thumbnails